# Structs in C++ can be modified? or there is a restriction?

Tags: c++, struct

I have this class which has a double list template of a struct of two chars and another struct

```
typedef struct KeyC{
     char K[5];
     char C[9];
} TKeyC;

typedef struct Bin{
     char Car;
     char Cad[9];
     TKeyC *KC;
} TBin;

class Bo {
    private:
        TDoubleList<TBin> *Ent;

    public:
            ...
}
```

I have a method to create nodes. No problem with this, but when I call other method to modify the direction of the pointer to a new TKeyC struct this simply doesn't happen.

```
TNode<TBin> *Aux;
TKeyC *AuxKC=new TKeyC;
Aux->getObj().KC=AuxKC;
```

Do I have to use a class instead of a struct in this case or is a problem of structs or there is a bug in it?

Update

```
template <class T>
class TNode
{
    private:
         T TObj;
         TNode<T> *Prev,*Next;

    public:
        TNode();
        ~TNode();
        TNode(T);
        void setObj(T);
        void sPrev(TNode<T>*);
        void sNext(TNode<T>*);
        T getObj();
        TNode<T>* gPrev();
            TNode<T>* gNext();
};
```

And the method getObj:

```
template <class T>
T TNode<T>::getObj() {return(TObj);};
```

Comment: What is the declaration for `getObj()`? You have given precious little information about what you're actually doing here; instead you have given information about what you *think* the problem is, which is probably unrelated. Please post a simple, complete, runnable example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: What type is `Aux` and what does `getObj` return.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I suspected, your `getObj()` function returns a *copy* of the object. I have upvoted David Crawshaw's answer which describes the problem in more detail.

Comment: Is it the same if i change the T TObj; for a pointer T *TObj; instead of changing T to T&

Comment: Yes, a pointer will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks David and thanks you all. I'm sorry for this newbie question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A structure in C++ is a class whose members are all public. If your assignment isn't changing the value you want it to, then you are not assigning to what you think you are.

Your `getObj()` function returns a copy of the structure, not a reference to the original. So you update the value in the copy, and the original remains unchanged.

Get a reference to your object, either by changing the return type of `getObj()`  to `T&` or adding another function if you have other code that depends on the behavior.

Comment: I think this is exactly it.  Change the return type of getObj from T to T&.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use the keyword typedef when you are declaring an struct ?

Comment: Old 'C' coding habits die hard, I would guess.

Comment: That's right, can't control my habits. This would be better? struct { ... } TKeyC;

Comment: No, it should be just `struct TKeyC { ... };`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
TBin x = Aux->getObj();
x.KC=AuxKC;
```

If getObj() is returning a pointer to the object, use `x->KC=AuxKC`